# How do I delete a row when two dataframes in pandas do not have the same length? - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have two dataframes in pandas:

df1 can have 365 or 366 rows

df2 has 366 rows

If df1 and df2 have the same number of rows I want to output "same row size".
If, df1 and df2 don't have the same sizes I want to delete row 59 at df2.

all because of leap year :)

Comment: There is column with `date` ? Or datetimeindex?

Comment: Its a good idea to show the code you are using and an example of the data you have, so we can see what you are working with and then more easily help with the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
if len(df1) != len(df2):
    df2 = df2.drop(59)
```

Another idea is remove row with `29. Feb`, how do it depends of data.